# icCube Reporting Drilldown - Changing Axis and Title on selection events

Tags: iccube-reporting

When activating a drilldown behaviour in the widget's navigation panel i'm trying to understand how to change the title and the axis label based on some complex logic.

I would like to write some articulated function that changes some part of the graph (title, category labels) by a custom logic.

Comment: That's complicated for now, give us some time to think this out